# Can my university network IT see the IP address of the obfs4 bridge node?

Tags: bridge, ip-address, obfs4, node, login

Can my university network IT see the IP address of the obfs4 bridge node when I use my private laptop computer and Tor Browser to log in my university network account and connect to the Tor network?

The university network IT does not use Deep Packet Inspection, and the university network IT does not require me to install special software to log in my account.

If the university network IT is unable to see the IP address of the obfs4 bridge node, why is the university network IT unable to see the IP address of the obfs4 bridge node?

Comment: You asked basically the same question twice in a row. I already answered the other question with multiple links on how obfs4 and bridges works.

Comment: Your answer fails to address whether the university network IT can see the IP address of the obfs4 node. Tor protocol and IP address are two separate things. Four different possibilities exist for what exactly the university network IT can or cannot see:  


1. Cannot see Tor protocol; cannot see IP address.  

   
2. Cannot see Tor protocol; can see IP address.   


3. Can see Tor protocol; cannot see IP address.  


3. Can see Tor protocol; can see IP address.

Comment: The links that I provided contains all of the information about obfs4 that the Tor Project has provided. If you need more information, then your next step is to contact the developers directly.